# How to get the parent of an element in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```html
<div class="field select-container invalid" data-tooltip="Error message." "name="birthDate">
<div class="stack-wrap gutter-col-wrap-1">
<div class="stack size1of3">
<div class="gutter-col-1">
    <div class="form-selectbox full-width">
    <select name="day">
        <option value="">Giorno</option>
        <option value="01">1</option>
```

When used WebElement el = browser.switchTo().activeElement(), the focus is on "name" attribute. Need to find the parent which is "data-tooltip" in order to get the error message on the screen. Please help.

Comment: "the focus is on "name" attribute"? Could you please clarify? "Need to find the parent which is "data-tooltip""? Did you mean find the div with 'data-tooltip' attribute?

Comment: Yes, exactly!! need to find div with 'data-tooltip' attribute. The tooltip is found throughout the page. So in order to get the current tooltip focus on a specific element, i did browser.switchTo().activeElement(), then when i do el.getText(), it gives me the text of the current element on focus. But there is a situation when the focus is on one of the "name" attribute. Now in order get the tooltip, i need to traverse back. The data-tooltip is present is a lot of places having different texts. So accessing the text directly through data-tooltip is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to find the data-tooltip's text from the `div.select-container`for `<select name="day">'` only

Here's how you do that in Java with xpath's ancestor selector (untested code):

```java
WebElement selectDayContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='day']//ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'select-container')]"));
String toolTip = selectDayContainer.getAttribute("data-tooltip");
```

Answer (score 16):

For finding just parent of child element following code can be used.

```
IWebElement parentElement = childElement.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
```